# Open sets in the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the set $Y=[-1,1]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the standard topology. Which of the following sets are open in $Y$? Open in $\mathbb{R}$?
>
> $A=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}:\frac{1}{2}<|x|<1 \rbrace$
>
> $B=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}:\frac{1}{2}<|x|\leq1 \rbrace$
>
> $C=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}:\frac{1}{2}\leq|x|<1 \rbrace$
>
> $D=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}:\frac{1}{2}\leq|x|\leq1 \rbrace$
>
> $E=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}:0<|x|<1$ and $\frac{1}{x} \notin \mathbb{N}$ $\rbrace$

I think I have figured out $A,B,C$, and $D$, but just looking for some help proving some of them rigorously. I don't know where to start with $E$.

Firstly, we rewrite $A=(-1,\frac{-1}{2}) \cup (\frac{1}{2},1)$, $B=[-1,\frac{-1}{2}) \cup (\frac{1}{2},1]$, $C=(-1,\frac{-1}{2}] \cup [\frac{1}{2},1)$, and $D=[-1,\frac{-1}{2}] \cup [\frac{1}{2},1]$.

We know sets are open in the subspace topology if they can be expressed as the intersection of $Y$ and some open set of $\mathbb{R}$. $A\subset Y$, so $A \cap Y=A$; also, $A$ is a union of basis elements of $\mathbb{R}$, so it is open in both $Y$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

If we let $U=(-2,\frac{-1}{2}) \cup (\frac{1}{2},2)$, then $B=U \cap Y$, and clearly $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, so $B$ is open in $Y$ (but not in $\mathbb{R}$; it is a union of half-open, half-closed intervals).

For $C$, I am reasonably certain that it is not open in $Y$, nor in $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm not sure how to express it formally. The problem is that we can't use the same trick we did for $B$, because we need our intersection to be closed on the $\frac{-1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ ends, but these are not endpoints of $Y$.

Same story for $D$ - it isn't open in either space.

Comment: You know that the open sets in the subspace topology are the intersection of open sets of the space and the subspace. So, try to see ih those sets can be seen as the intersection of the space $Y$ with an open set of $Y$. Hope this suggestion helps you in someway.

Answer (score 2):

You can check all of them by checking the complements.

$Y \setminus A = [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}] \cup \{-1\} \cup \{1\}$ which is closed.

$Y \setminus B = [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ which is closed.

$Y \setminus C = (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) \cup \{-1\} \cup \{1\}$ which is NOT closed.

$Y \setminus D = (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ which is NOT closed.

$Y \setminus E = \{\frac{1}{x} \mid x\in \Bbb Z^*\} \cup \{0\}$ which is closed since it contains all of its limit point (i.e. $0$). (Sorry for the mistake made before)

As for using definition directly, $E = \{\bigcup (\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{x+1}) \mid x \in \Bbb Z^+) \} \cup \{\bigcup (\frac{1}{x-1},\frac{1}{x}) \mid x \in \Bbb Z^-) \}$, which is a union of open set, so it is open. Apply subspace topology, it is still open in $Y$.

Comment: I like your method. However these exercises appear before the book introduces limit points and closed sets (even though I understand what they mean from analysis), so I'd be interested in solutions that don't use these too.

Comment: @Ducky I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the complements is a good method. But you can directly know which one is open or not by a useful theorem:

First, given an ordered set $X$, let us say that a subset $Y$ of $X$ is **convex** in $X$ if for each pair of points $a<b$ of $Y$, the entire interval $(a, b)$ of points of $X$ lies in $Y$.

**Theorem**: Let $X$ be an ordered set in the order topology; let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ that is convex in $X$. Then the order topology on $Y$ is the same as the topology $Y$ inherits as a subspace of $X$.

Now, since $Y=[-1,1]$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$, the subspace topology of $Y$ is just the order topology of $Y$ whose base is the family of all intervals of forms $[-1,a),(a,b)$ and $(a,1]$. For example, $B=[-1,-\frac{1}{2})\bigcup(\frac 12,1]$ is open in $Y$ but is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.